# How to create ten thousand objects and store them in a HashMap

Tags: java, object, dictionary, hashmap

I am learning Java and have a pretty basic problem.

I am indexing some sites with a BufferedReader and storing the data in a MySQL-base. I do this for 30 sources every 15 seconds, which generate a lot of data.

Now I want to analyze this data. I am thinking of storing the data simultaneously in a `HashMap` which I will clear at the end of the day, every day.

But can you give me an example on how to create an object for 30 different sources?
Do I need 30 different `HashMap` or can I build a key like 'pathName+randomNumber'?

In the end I want to be able to locate the first entry in the HashMap for each source and the two latest entries thereby enabling me to see what the difference between these three are.

Please help. I have tried to look on the web but with no luck as I think the HashMap examples are always focused towards storing Objects, but not on how to create the objects you store in them... (yeah I know - it's a rookie question) ;)

Comment: "locate the first entry ", "the two latest entries". What defines this order? Insertion time?

Comment: You have to engineer a custom, fine tuned data structure, that might (or not) use the JCF classes. You can for example create a Map where the key is the source and the value is a LinkedList, in which you list the entries related to that certain source. But you have to focus on what you have to do with this data: you didn't give us enough information. Is FULL sorting relevant, or you just have to know the first and the two last? Is O(1) retrieval essential? Why and how? More: "how to create the objects" means nothing. In java you create objects by new'ing. What you mean, so?

Comment: If you want an ordered collection (based on insertion order) use a LinkedHashMap. If you want a sorted map, then use TreeMap and implement Comparable on the objects or use a Comparator. In addition, you could elaborate a bit more on the problem, as you don't say what kind of objects are you using, nor if the process must involve the 30 subproblems as a whole or you could just process these one by one.

Comment: Can you not analyze your data by querying your database (when such analysis is required) rather than keeping all data in memory all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jobu, I would do exactly as you proposed. So in a sense you answered your question already. :) Whenever I had a similar situation, and had to use a Map, I use forward slashes to form a hierarchy of objects. So, say you want to distinguish data that come from 30 sources as you say. - Give those sources a unique name, and form your Map keys using this simple pattern: "`/<root>/<source id>/<data id>`" . Example of storing a link on some website: `mymap.put("/myproject/www.example.com/link-0121", "http://www.kernel.org");`

If, for some reason you want to get all Map entries that have keys equal to "`/myproject/www.example.com`", then I suggest you List objects only to your map! Here is a pseudo-code for that case:

```
ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();
lst.add("http://www.kernel.org");
mymap.put("/myproject/www.example.com", lst); // www.example.com has a link to www.kernel.org
```

This approach works only if your data can be uniquely identified by a number. Then you simply use List's get() method which has index as parameter.

However, if you need to have string keys for data, I am afraid you need to make Map of Maps (ie. use HashMap instead of the ArrayList).

Comment: Hi Dejan! Thanks!! Now I know how to handle the key ;) But my real problem is still, that I don't know how to store an objects in the map. As an example I want to store the following variables: articleLength, artTitle, artDate etc. How do I create this as an object and store it in the above mentioned hierachy? Then I want to make a new method which can add new information to the map; eg take the first input of articleLength from the day and the last two inputs and compare these. And then analyze the difference like the article is longer so I add "Longer" to the newest line. Can you help?

Comment: I have the data, I just need to know how to add it to an object - and then store it in the Map. Do they need to have different object names or ... Yeah, it's a newbie question, I know :) But I have no clue...

Comment: Simply make a Class for them. Something like: `public class MyData { public long length; public String title; public Date date; }` and then instead of a String, you will put MyData objects into your List or Map. :)

Comment: But you will create it like this right:
MyData objectName = new MyData(artLength, artTitle, artDate);

But then the objectName will be the same at all time? Can you add that then? Like in ur example:
lst.add(objectName);
mymap.put(artSource + i, lst);

Would that be how to do it?

Comment: MyData (the way I wrote it) acts like a C/C++/D struct. That is why I made all members public. Unfortunately Java does not allow us to make value types, so we have to stick to what we can use as such. :) You basically make thousends of new MyData objects. Example: `ArrayList<MyData> lst = new ArrayList<MyData>(); lst.add(new MyData(10000, "Some title", new Date())); lst.add(new MyData(34523, "Main google page", new Date())));`

Comment: Okay, cool - then you just add the lst to the mymap like this right: mymap.put(artSource + i, lst);

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use a `Map` on pathname in which you store `List`s containing the data objects. This would allow you to retrieve them in the order you inserted them.

Instead of a `List` you could also store `Map`s from Long (timestamp of the fetch) to your data object.

What would be the best method depends on how you want to use the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a map that has `String` as a *key* (source) and `List<String>` as its *value* (web page data).

```
Map<String, List<String>> map;
```